# How to get back Nvidia graphics drivers without an internet connection

Tags: drivers, nvidia, network-manager, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10. In my Ubuntu 22.04 suddenly from *Additional Drivers* in *Software & Updates*, as shown in the attached image, at first there were only the first two options and the first option was active. I activated the second option, and after restarting, the third option named *Continue using a manually installed driver* was activated.  I can not change it.  What do I do?

[image: Drivers]

After restarting my entire internet network has been removed from the settings and I have no internet access. I cannot even connect with my phone.

[image: Network settings]

Comment: Disable the wireless driver. Nvidia drivers are installed.

Comment: @Pilot6
Please explain more

Comment: In the current state Nvidia drivers are installed, so you don't need to get them back. By clicking the Broadcom driver option you probably installed a wrong wireless driver and broke your network connection. There is no more to add with this incoming information.